# Linq Date Distinct as String yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, date, datetime

I have a date sql variable i retrive with a Linq statement however i need it to be in a format like 'yyyy-MM-dd' but i dotn know how to do this in c#

This is my Linq:

```
  List<string> listItem2 = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in db.Pos.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
        {
            string dateday = Convert.ToString(item);
            string lines = dateday.Split(' ')[0];
            listItem2.Add(item.ToString());
        }
```

How ever my output ends like this 'dd/mm/yyyy' how can i make it 'yyyy-MM-dd'??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  string dateday = item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

So your loop will be like the following:

```
 foreach (var item in db.Pos.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
    {
        string dateday = item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string lines = dateday.Split('-')[0];
        listItem2.Add(item.ToString());
    }
```

Instead for `Convert.ToString(item);` for displaying date in the given format(`"yyyy-mm-dd"`).

Comment: It's `yyyy-MM-dd` and not `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yep, thanks i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> listItem2 = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in db.Pos.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
   listItem2.Add(item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```